# On Linux, how do I allow Steam to download games into the root drive?

Tags: permissions, partition, software-installation, steam

On Linux, how do I allow Steam to download games into the root drive? Space on my home drive is very limited, but trying to create a new library folder in `/usr` throws the error "Drive is read-only".

Specifics:
I am on Pop!_OS dual-booting with Windows and I've set up the boot, home and swap partitions on my SSD with 2, 10 and 2 GB respectively, but have set the root partition to be on my HDD, which allowed me to allocate more space since Windows isn't on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The filesystem itself probably isn't read only, although you can double check that it's not mounted with `ro` in `/proc/mounts`. What's more likely is that, since `/usr` is owned by root and typically has 755/rwxr-xr-x permissions, you're simply not allowed to write directly inside that directory to create a new directory for your Steam library.

To allow you to do so, you need to first create a subdirectory that has write access for your user (/opt is generally a better place for these system-independent installations, but you can do it under /usr, too, if you want):

```
# as the user you run steam as
sudo mkdir /opt/steamlibrary
sudo chown "$(id -un)" /opt/steamlibrary
```

Now you should be able to create your Steam library under `/opt/steamlibrary`.